# Cors Policy issue in Spring boot : Custom Header Problem

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

We are developing a spring boot and angularjs app.We are using JWT token along with LDAP authentication.
After LDAP authentication service is generating jwt token and sending to Angular.From next time onwards angular is sending the token and username back to service.Angular is storing the token in session storage.

The Problem we are facing is: **whenever angular is sending this token and user name as request header attribute **from Angular interceptor** **we are cors policy error in browser console and service is not getting invoked.**

Angular code:

```
setHeaders: {
    "customHeader1":"userName",
    "customHeader2":"jwtToken"
 }
```

Service Level configuration:

```
@Configuration
 public class CustomSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*").permitAll();
        http.cors();
    }

   @Bean
   public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    List<String> originList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> methodList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> headerList = new ArrayList<String>();
    originList.add("*"); 
    methodList.add("HEAD");methodList.add("GET");methodList.add("POST");methodList.add("PUT");
    methodList.add("DELETE");methodList.add("PATCH");
    headerList.add("Authorization");
    headerList.add("Cache-Control");
    headerList.add("Content-Type");
    headerList.add("customHeader1");
    headerList.add("customHeader2");
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.unmodifiableList(originList)); 
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.unmodifiableList(methodList));
    // setAllowCredentials(true) is important, otherwise:
    // The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    // setAllowedHeaders is important! Without it, OPTIONS preflight request
    // will fail with 403 Invalid CORS request
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.unmodifiableList(headerList));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
   }
```

I also have a interceptor in spring boot as below:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
    String header1 = null;
    String header2 = null;

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getHeader("customHeader1"))) {
            header1 = request.getHeader("customHeader1");
        }
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(request.getHeader("customHeader2"))) {
            header2 = request.getHeader("customHeader2");
        }
        System.out.println("customtoken="+header1+"|customUserName="+header2); 

            //LDAP service call


                if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(response, "success")) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    response.setStatus(<CUSTOM_ERROR_CODE>); //custom error code
                    return false;
                }
          } 
      }
   }
```

Interceptor has been registered in following way:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
   @Autowired
   private CustomAuthInterceptor customAuthInterceptor ;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
       registry.addInterceptor(customAuthInterceptor);
    }

   @Override
   public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
       registry.addMapping("/**")
       .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH");
    }
  }
```

Still we are getting following error in browser console when angular is trying to send custom Headers to service:

***Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://customUrl' from origin 'http://server port' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field customHeader1 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.***

Can anyone has any solution to this????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pre-flight request was blocked because you didn't enabled `OPTIONS` request type.

Add this statement to your Cors Bean configuration.

```
methodList.add("OPTIONS");
```